# can I use Tornado without any proxy?

Tags: proxy, tornado

I am using [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) for a small blog which may get around 500-1k visits / day ,
is it ok to use tornado without any proxy in front of it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and no

If you start Tornado on port 80, you can use it stand-alone but you shouldn't. Tornado is really bad at static files, it wasn't built to serve static files, and shouldn't be serving static files, it was put there just to make things a bit easyer during development. You'd be much better off putting an NGINX instance in front of your single node, as described in their documentation.

NGINX also gives you lots of other features like static caching, easy header manipulation and better logging/error handling

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am using external server for serving static files (css, js ,etc ) . I have tried running on port 80 and it does work , but is there any security risk in running it on port 80 ?

Comment: Yes, to run it on port 80 you would have to run it as root which has lots of security risks, if you do want it on port 80 you should run it on a higher port (say 8000) then map port 80 to 8000 with IPTables